# Bootsy WYSIWYG input in a Rails application not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Upon inspecting, all bootsy assets seem to be loading: JS, CSS and text-area=bootsy shows on the section targeted [section 1]. I have enabled basic features in the initializer and included bootsy container in my model. **Bootsy** is not showing up at all, and need help seeing why that is. Here is what I've got:

**Versions:**
Ruby 2.1.2, Rails 4.1

**Model**

```
class About < ActiveRecord::Base
include Bootsy::Container
end
```

**View**: _form.html.erb

```
<%= casein_text_area f, f.object, :section_1, as: :bootsy %>
```

HTML Output:

```
 <textarea as="bootsy" class="form-control" id="about_section_1" name="about[section_1]">
 Hello Lorem Ipsum
 </textarea>
```

**Files being loaded:**

/assets/bootsy/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css?body=1
/assets/bootsy/bootsy.css?body=1" 
/assets/bootsy/wysihtml5.js?body=1"
/assets/bootsy/bootstrap-wysihtml5.js?body=1"
/assets/bootsy/bootsy.js?body=1"
/assets/bootsy/bootstrap.file-input.js?body=1
/assets/bootsy/init.js
/assets/bootsy/editor_options.js
/assets/bootsy/translations.js?body=1
/assets/bootsy.js?body=1

Answer (score 0):

To get this working I changed my view to:

```
<%= casein_text_area f, f.object, :section_1, class: :bootsy_text_area %>
```