# Rails4: Bootsy WYSIWYG editor not displaying

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, wysiwyg, bootstrap-wysihtml5

I just migrated from Paperclip to CarrierWave and can't get the Bootsy WYSIWYG editor to display. My form (and its text field, which is now `<%= f.bootsy_area :text, rows: 12 %>`) looks exactly like it did before I installed Bootsy. Any ideas as to how I can make the editor display instead of the old textarea alone? Thanks.

**Steps I've taken already:**

1. followed [Bootsy instructions](https://github.com/volmer/bootsy) on Github
2. compared all pages of [bootsy demo](https://github.com/volmer/bootsy-demo) app code to mine
3. read relevant Bootsy [known issues](https://github.com/volmer/bootsy/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aclosed)
4. restarted server
5. ran **bundle update bootsy** and restarted server
6. removed fontawesome from application.scss
7. read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594898/rails-4-wysiwyg-bootsy-not-displaying-formatting) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27383692/bootsy-wysiwyg-input-in-a-rails-application-not-loading) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907596/wysiwyg-editor-not-showing-html-button) SO question

**Gemfile:**

```
`source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.0'
gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.6'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.5', '>= 3.5.6'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.2'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.66'
gem 'figaro', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.1'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'mail_form'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 3.4'
gem 'fog'
gem 'rmagick', '~> 2.15', '>= 2.15.4'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem "fog-aws"
gem 'bootsy', github: 'volmer/bootsy'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc`
```

**article.rb**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Bootsy::Container
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { large: "900x900>", medium: "500x500>", thumb: "250x250>" }
  belongs_to :user
  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
end
```

**articles_controller.rb**

```
private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :image, :user_id, :subtitle, :tag_list, :bootsy_image_gallery_id)
  end
```

**application.js:**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootsy
//= require_tree .
```

**application.scss:**

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootsy";
@import "font-awesome"; 
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Delius+Swash+Caps);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Reenie+Beanie);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina+Shadow);
```

**_form.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for @article, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>

  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this article from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :image %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :subtitle %>
    <%= f.text_field :subtitle %>
  </p>

  <%= f.label :text %>
  <%= f.bootsy_area :text, rows: 12%>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :tags %>
    <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
```

**new.html.erb:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

            <h1>New article</h1>
                    <%= render 'form' %>
                    <%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**assets.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( bootsy/gallery-loader.gif )

#CSS

Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( bootstrap.min.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( animate.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( bootstrap.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( bootstrapTheme.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( custom.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( general.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( magnific-popup.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( owl.carousel.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( owl.theme.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( style.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( bootsy.css )
```

**Article column headings according to rails console**

```
> Article.column_names
 => ["id", "title", "text", "created_at", "updated_at", "image_file_name", "image_content_type", "image_file_size", "image_updated_at", "user_id", "subtitle", "image"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I solved it by moving //=require tree. higher than //=require bootsy . I can not explain why and how but worked for me.

application.js

```
`//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootsy`
```